# pyproj converted coordinates offset

Tags: python, coordinates, proj

I'm using pyproj to convert some coordinates from WGS84 to OSGB36. When mapped out the converted and unconverted don't map to the same places on a map. The OSGB36 coordinates are mapped about 100 meters north west of where they ought to be.

Does anyone know what might be wrong here?

Here's an example of what I'm doing in code

```
import pyproy
wgs84=pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")
osgb36=pyproj.Proj("+init=EPSG:27700")
row = pyproj.transform(wgs84, osgb36, lng, lat)
```

Comment: I have also posted this question to gis.stackexchange.com http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69051/proj-pyproj-converted-coordinates-offset

Comment: What map/tool are you using for comparing the coordinates?

Comment: @user613068 I'm using QGIS

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it has to do with the older version of PROJ inside of pyproj 1.x.

I would recommend upgrading to pyproj 2.2.0 and see how it compares:

```py
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.__version__
'2.2.0'
>>> pyproj.proj_version_str
'6.1.0'
>>> from pyproj import Transformer, CRS
>>> transformer = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:27700")
>>> transformer
<Unknown Transformer: unknown>
unavailable until proj_trans is called
>>> CRS("EPSG:27700")
<Projected CRS: EPSG:27700>
Name: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: UK - Britain and UKCS 49°46'N to 61°01'N, 7°33'W to 3°33'E
- bounds: (-9.2, 49.75, 2.88, 61.14)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: British National Grid
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: OSGB 1936
- Ellipsoid: Airy 1830
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

>>> transformer.transform(-1, 55)
(8171674.7989976285, -5732606.974077599)
```